# Enter value to stack 2 dimensional in c

Tags: c

i have this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define MAXCOL 3
#define MAXROW 3

typedef struct {
    int arr[MAXCOL][MAXROW];
}GAME;

void createGame(GAME *G){
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<=MAXCOL; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=MAXROW; j++){
            (*G).arr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

but when i compile it, the output looks like this

```
[0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][0]
[0][0][0][-1]
[-1][1][0][0]
```

how is that possible, where is -1, -1, and 1 come from?

Comment: `for(i=0; i<=MAXCOL; i++){` --> `for(i=0; i<MAXCOL; i++){`, same for `MAXROW`

Comment: Thats impossible, your code doesn't print anything. There isn't even a main.

Comment: Your code looks like it will get all of the array (and more see comment be Keine Lust) set to 0. There must be more with an influence. Please make a [mcve].

Comment: As Keine mentioned, you need to fix the <= to < - otherewise, you're writing off the end of you allocted memory.  At that point, who knows what will happen since you might be overwriting arbitrary data.  (Or, you could fix the initialization to allocate MAXROW + 1 and MAXCOL + 1 sized arrays

Comment: Your array has `3*3=9` elements. But you have assigned and printed `16` elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the names MAXCOL and MAXROW are to be believed (that you want a col 3 and row 3), then you might fix it by doing:

```
typedef struct {
    int arr[MAXCOL+1][MAXROW+1];
}GAME;
```

That way you will actually allocate enough space for 4 (0,1,2,3) rows and 4 columns.

Comment: Oh right, thx sir. This fixes my problem

Answer (score 0):

The array dimensions are `int arr[MAXCOL][MAXROW];`
Thus only indices `arr[i][j]` with `0<=i<MAXCOL` and `0<=j<MAXROW` are allowed, otherwise you have an array out of range error.

In your case you are overwritting Memory which does not belong to the array and your program will have undefined behaviour.